# How to know the "name" of an input field of a commerce checkout form?

Tags: forms, commerce

I need to find the name of an input field of a commerce checkout form to use in:

```
form_set_error('NAME-HERE', t('Field cannot be left blank'));
```

The html of the field is:

```
<div class="field-type-text field-name-field-cif-nif-id field-widget-text-textfield form-wrapper" id="edit-customer-profile-billing-field-cif-nif-id">
    <div id="customer-profile-billing-field-cif-nif-id-add-more-wrapper">
        <div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-customer-profile-billing-field-cif-nif-id-und-0-value">
             <label for="edit-customer-profile-billing-field-cif-nif-id-und-0-value">CIF/NIF/ID <span class="form-required">*</span></label>
             <input class="text-full form-text" type="text" id="edit-customer-profile-billing-field-cif-nif-id-und-0-value" name="customer_profile_billing[field_cif_nif_id][und][0][value]" value="" size="20" maxlength="20">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried with all of these, but it didn't work.

```
customer_profile_billing[field_cif_nif_id][und][0][value]

customer_profile_billing_field_cif_nif_id_und_0_value

customer_profile_billing-field_cif_nif_id-und-0-value

customer-profile-billing-field-cif-nif-id-und-0-value

customer_profile_billing_field_cif_nif_id
```

If I use

```
dpm($form_state['values']);
```

I get this:

[image]

Comment: Try `customer_profile_billing[field_cif_nif_id][und][0][value` (no end square bracket)

Comment: @Clive no, it doesn't work. Used in line 26 of this code http://pastebin.com/AF5QpBK8

Comment: Try `form_error($form['customer_profile_billing']['field_cif_nif_id']['und'][0]['value'], 'msg');` and variations on that

Comment: @Clive  I get an error message: `Notice: Undefined index: val‌​ue in utilities_custom_validate_required_field()...`

Comment: @Clive None of these variations worked: `$form_state['customer-profile-billing-field-cif-nif-id-und-0-value']`  ,   `$form_state['customer_profile_billing_field_cif_nif_id_und_0_value']`

Comment: Give a try to this: `form_set_error('customer_profile_billing][field_cif_nif_id', t('This field failed validation'));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a try to this:

> form_set_error('customer_profile_billing][field_cif_nif_id', t('This field failed validation'));